# iGraph in C (xcode), compile error

Tags: c, xcode, igraph

I'm the project's head New to C, I want to try iGraph's C library to check if my algorithm can run faster. I installed iGraph's C library on my mac using homebrew as this page suggests: http://igraph.org/c/. Then I started Xcode, selected "create a new project", "application", and "Command Line Tool".

In main.c, I pasted this example from iGraph's tutorials:

```
#include <igraph.h>

int main(void)
{
    igraph_integer_t diameter;
    igraph_t graph;
    igraph_rng_seed(igraph_rng_default(), 42);
    igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&graph, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 1000, 5.0/1000,
                            IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);
    igraph_diameter(&graph, &diameter, 0, 0, 0, IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, 1);
    printf("Diameter of a random graph with average degree 5: %d\n",
           (int) diameter);
    igraph_destroy(&graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Xcode raises a compile error message:

> "igraph.h" file not found

I'm guessing Xcode's header search path isn't properly set for where home brew installed iGraph. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: That is a header, not a library. Real men don't read manuals, eh?

Comment: Well, that was uncalled for... :D My understanding is that #include <igraph.h> tries to link my short example to the iGraph library... If so, the error message makes my think Xcode can't find the graph library for some reason...

Comment: Well, your understanding is wrong actually. A header does not link anything. I strongly recommend to read a good C book. That should explain the process and the terms.

Comment: Oh boy, you seem cranky... I'll see if someone else can help me with this while I'm working on it!

Comment: You will need to include the library in the project file at the top of the left column. Your system is probably looking at the a different location for the framework. The area will look like a list, with a +/- under it. Locate the framework then this might work better. If that doesn't work you might have to use terminal to link the libraries to the c file.

Comment: Actually not. That was a well-meant recommendation. Using the proper phrases will help you get the search terms right so you can find an answer yourself next time and help others to sort your question correctly, so you will get better and faster answers.